# ObjectDataProvider with MethodName , Refresh not working

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I am a newbie to WPF. I had created a window for adding customers and wrote the code-behind in VB and everything works fine: The entry is inserted into the database successfully. Now, I have a problem in refreshing the dataGrid.

Here's my DataGridBinding

```
<Datagrid  Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" IsReadOnly="True"  x:Name ="DGCustomers"  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PopulateCustomers}}" />
```

Whenever I call 
`Me.TryCast(Me.FindResource("PopulateCustomers"), ObjectDataProvider).Refresh()`
Nothing happens!. Only when I restart the application, I am able to see the changes!
Here's my XAML

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="PopulateCustomers" ObjectType="{x:Type local:CustomersDataProvider}" MethodName="LoadDG" />
```

Here's my class

```
Public Class CustomersDataProvider
 Dim con As String = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= C:\Users\Nothing But WIND\Documents\DBSAMPLE.accdb"
        Dim oc As New OleDbConnection(con)
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("SELECT * FROM Customers", oc)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        Public Sub New()
            da.Fill(ds)
            dt = ds.Tables(0)

        End Sub
        Public Function LoadDG()
            Return dt.DefaultView
        End Function
    End Class
```

Here's my updation code

```
 Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click
        Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select * FROM Customers", oc)
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(ds)
        dt = ds.Tables(0)

        dt.Rows.Add(txt_CustomerID.Text, txt_CustomerName.Text, txt_ContactPerson.Text, txt_Address.Text, txt_Area.Text, txt_City.Text, txt_Pincode.Text, txt_Number.Text, Chk_1Discount.IsChecked)
        If oc.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            oc.Open()

        End If

        Dim cb As OleDbCommandBuilder = New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
        da.InsertCommand = cb.GetInsertCommand
        da.Update(dt)
        oc.Close()
        MsgBox("Item added")
        TryCast(Me.FindResource("PopulateCustomers"), ObjectDataProvider).Refresh()
        DGCustomers.Items.Refresh()

    End Sub
```

Any help is heart-fully appreciated!